# Joomla Ajax download text editor

Tags: ajax, joomla, editor

I'm trying to figure out how to load an editor box using Ajax
this is for the admin side structure looks like admin

-controllers

--orderitem.php

-views

--orderitem

---tmpl

----orderitem.php

---view.raw

---view.html

-controller.php

I've built and have working ajax passing a json object to the server and back.  Currently it passes a plain text field back.:

```
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
   $test = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
 }else{
   $test = $_POST['json']; 
 }
 $obj = json_decode($test);//  passes data up to the $obj
 $obj->{'postsHolder'} = "
 <div>
   Message:<br>
   <textarea id='message".$invoiceid."' rows='15' cols='60' >
     test text                
   </textarea><br>          
 </div>";
 $reply = json_encode($obj);        
 echo $reply;
 JFactory::getApplication()->close();
```

then I just load the returned object into a div using mootools:

```
$(targetdiv).setProperty('html',jsonObj.postsHolder);
```

I know it's possible to use a joomla text editor but can't figure out how to do it with AJAX. I'm guessing I need to do something with XML since I've used that before to get a text editor in my components (just not through AJAX)

Any help would be really great

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your problem is but hope this helps.

To get the editor from Joomla you need to call it this way

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
             'style'  => '1' ,  
             'layer'  => '0' , 
             'table'  => '0' ,
             'clear_entities'=>'0'
             );
echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
```

See [JFactory/getEditor](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor)

Comment: hi this kind of works but the $editor->display throws and error
 Call to undefined method JDocumentRaw::addCustomTag()

Comment: Remove the "format=raw" from the URL and exit with jexit() from the script. See if this helps. I don't think the Editor is designed to work with JDocumentRaw.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work.  Perhaps these components can't be used in this way although I'd have thought creating a text editor on the fly would be an obvious thing to do.  It's pretty straighforward if you don't use joomla

Comment: Basically the editor is just JavaScript based. So you should check other resources on how to do this.